# Nullable enabled, but 'Value cannot be null'

Tags: c#, database, wpf, postgresql, nullable

I'm creating a database with PostgreSQL in C#.
My database should be able to import a CSV file and export its data to a CSV file.
The `Favorite` column should allow empty (null) data.
For example, the CSV file `cat.csv` looks like this:

```
1,AA,EE
2,BB,FF
3,CC,
4,DD,HH
```

When I try to export the stored data to CSV, the following error occurs:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 
'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'
```

..., even though nullable types are used:

```
#nullable enable
                List<Cat>? list = this.dataGrid.ItemsSource as List<Cat>;
#nullable restore
                String delimiter = ",";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
#nullable enable
                Cat? lastData = list.Last(); // 'Value cannot be null' Error
#nullable restore
```

It seems the first nullable type `List<Cat>?` works fine.
But, the second nullable type `Cat?` is not working.
If `lastData` cannot be null, what's this nullable type for?
How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

Cat.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    [Table("tblcat")]
    class Cat
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Column("no")]
        public int No { get; set; }
        [Column("name")]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Column("favorite")]
        public String Favorite { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CatModel.cs

```
using System;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class CatModel
    {
        public CatModel(int No, String Name, String Favorite)
        {
            this.IsChecked = false;
            this.No = No;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Favorite = Favorite;
        }
        public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; }
        public int No { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Favorite { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PgDbContext.cs

```
using Npgsql;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    class PgDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private const string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;User ID=USER01;Password=USER01;Database=DB01;port=5432";

        public PgDbContext() : base(new NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString), true) { }

        public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Configure default schema
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dora");
            Database.SetInitializer<PgDbContext>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="List" Height="350" Width="530"
        BorderThickness="1"
        >
    <Grid Height="350" Width="530">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rec_overlay" Width="530" Height="330"/>

        <Label Content="Name：" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="search_name" Margin="56,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="search_button" Content="Search" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Click="search_button_Click"/>

        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,43,0,0" Width="497" Height="225">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Select" Width="50">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding No}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="No" IsReadOnly="True" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Favorite}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Favorite" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="imp_button" Content="Import CSV" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="250,273,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="30" Click="imp_button_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="exp_button" Content="Export CSV" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,273,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="30" Click="exp_button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost; Port=5432; Database=DB01;User Id=USER01;Password=USER01;"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    sb.Clear();
                    sb.Append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dora.tblcat (");
                    sb.Append(" no INTEGER NOT NULL");
                    sb.Append(" , name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL");
                    sb.Append(" , favorite VARCHAR(40)");
                    sb.Append(" , PRIMARY KEY (no)");
                    sb.Append(")");

                    command.CommandText = sb.ToString();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                Actual_Search();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void search_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Actual_Search();
        }

        private void Actual_Search()
        {
            Object[] param = new Object[2];
            param[0] = this.search_name.Text;

            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += SearchProcess;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(SearchProcessCompleted);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(param);
        }

        private void searchData()
        {
            using (var context = new PgDbContext())
            {
                String searchName = this.search_name.Text;

                var tblCat = context.Cats;

                IQueryable<Cat> result;
                result = from x in tblCat
                         where x.Name.StartsWith(searchName)
                         orderby x.No
                         select x;
                this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
            }
        }

        private void SearchProcess(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var context = new PgDbContext())
            {
                String searchName = (e.Argument as Object[])[0] as String;

                var tblCat = context.Cats;

                IQueryable<Cat> result;
                result = from x in tblCat
                         where x.Name.StartsWith(searchName)
                         orderby x.No
                         select x;

                List<CatModel> resultList = new List<CatModel>();
                foreach (Cat cat in result.ToList())
                {
                    resultList.Add(new CatModel(cat.No, cat.Name, cat.Favorite));
                }
                e.Result = resultList;
            }
        }

        private void SearchProcessCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result as List<CatModel>;
        }

        private void imp_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.FileName = "";
            ofd.DefaultExt = "*.csv";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == false)
            {
                return;
            }

            List<Cat> list = readFile(ofd.FileName);

            int count = 0;
            using (var context = new PgDbContext())
            {
                var table = context.Cats;

                foreach (Cat cat in list)
                {
                    if (table.SingleOrDefault(x => x.No == cat.No) == null)
                    {
                        context.Cats.Add(cat);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(count + " / " + list.Count + " Data Imported");

            searchData();
            Actual_Search();
        }

        private static List<Cat> readFile(string filePath)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
            string ret = string.Empty;
            List<Cat> list = new List<Cat>();
            using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(fileInfo.FullName, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
            {
                tfp.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                tfp.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
                tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                tfp.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
                while (!tfp.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fields = tfp.ReadFields();
                    Cat cat = new Cat();
                    cat.No = int.Parse(fields[0]);
                    cat.Name = fields[1];
                    cat.Favorite = fields[2];
                    list.Add(cat);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

        private void exp_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();

            dlg.FileName = "cat.csv";
            dlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            dlg.Filter = "CSV File|*.csv|All Files|*.*";
            dlg.FilterIndex = 0;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
#nullable enable
                //List<Cat> list = this.dataGrid.ItemsSource as List<Cat>;
                List<Cat>? list = this.dataGrid.ItemsSource as List<Cat>;
#nullable restore
                String delimiter = ",";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
#nullable enable
                //Cat lastData = list.Last();
                Cat? lastData = list.Last();
#nullable restore
                foreach (Cat cat in list)
                {
                    sb.Append(cat.No).Append(delimiter);
                    sb.Append(cat.Name).Append(delimiter);
                    sb.Append(cat.Favorite);
                    if (!cat.Equals(lastData))
                    {
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                Stream st = dlg.OpenFile();
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(st, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));

                sw.Write(sb.ToString());
                sw.Close();
                st.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Exported to CSV");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `#nullable` doesn't influence runtime behavior. What's happening is that `this.DataGrid.ItemsSource` is not a subtype of `List<Cat>`

Comment: What is `this.dataGrid.ItemsSource.GetType()` when the exception occurs?

Comment: `It seems the first nullable type List<Cat>? works fine.` Yes, it works perfectly - it allows `null` to be assigned to the list.

Comment: I think part of the confusion is that (I suspect) you think if nullable enable is turned on then null will "magically work" (i.e. allow you to call methods on it, use LINQ with it etc). That isn't true - it doesn't do that at all.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Solved! You're right. `this.DataGrid.ItemsSource` was a subtype of List<Cat**Model**>. I changed the rest of `Cat`s in the function to `CatModel`, then worked. Could you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @mjwills Thank you! `Console.WriteLine(this.dataGrid.ItemsSource.GetType());` returned `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WpfApp1.CatModel]`. That's why I found that `List<CatModel>` should have been used.